# Why are my variables being omitted by Stata?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, interaction, stata, multicollinearity

I'm doing a random effects model. I have a dummy per treatment, which would be "Message", "MessageTax", "Tax" and "Donation" which refers to whether or not the experiment included a donation. The data comes from 2 similar experiments, but one was with a donation and the other was not, so the Message, Tax and MessageTax treatments are in both experiments.
This appears in Stata when I run this regression:

xtreg q Mensaje MensajeImpuesto Impuesto Donacion Donacion##Mensaje Donacion##MensajeImpuesto Donacion##Impuesto,re

How can I fix it?
[image]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: It might help if you also add a translation of the error into your question.

Comment: This type of omission of coefficients for variables happens when there are redundant predictors in the model. I don't use Stata, so I might be missing some subtlety, but [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/400209/28500) seems very closely related to your question, with 2 answers that might point you in the correct direction. If that's the case, there's nothing to "fix"; your data simply contain multiple predictors that are linearly dependent.

Comment: You have left out the first part of the output which contains crucial details about sample size.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just added the full image in case you can see something else
 @NickCox

Comment: The message is clear and explicit.  For more information, search our site for "collinear*".